# Executing Edify script via adb shell

Tags: adb, scripts

[Edify script](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/nonab/inside_packages) is a very limited language that is being used in flashable zips (mostly `updater-script` files);

Within Edify script we can execute shell commands (`run_program()`) but what about the vice versa? Is there anyway/tool to execute Edify script via `adb shell`?

Comment: `updater-script` alone is useless. All the Edify functions which are called in scripts are defined in a binary file named `update-binary`, just like shell functions are defined in a shell interpreter binary like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh` etc. Both files `updater-script` and `update-binary` are packaged in ZIP file (inside `META-INF/com/google/android/`). `update-binary` is executed with 3 arguments. Second one is the FD you need to create where to print the output. Third one is the path to the ZIP file which is extracted and commands in `updater-script` are executed in sequence.

Comment: You need to simulate this behavior exactly, in order to run Edify script from a shell. Normally this doesn't worth the hassle. Just translate the Edify script to a shell script and run directly.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the info.

Comment: @IrfanLatif but some functions are not implemented in the shell; for example functions for managing Dynamic Partitions operations (such as `resize`, `remove`, `add_group` ...)

Comment: you can install flashable zip from TWRP command line https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Comment: @alecxs yes, but that's the hard way (I have to write updater-script and put it into a flashable zip); I'm looking for a more straightforward way; like direct execution of commands in adb shell;